# In $P(X\leq q)=\alpha$, what do we call $q$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, terminology

This is a simple question, but in $P(X\leq q)=\alpha$, what do we call $q$?

I sometimes call them quantiles, for lack of a better word. My basis for that comes from the quantile function,
which for continuous distributions (and with increasing CDF) we'll have $Q(\alpha)=q$.
However, this is not very correct, I think.

This is probably a very dumb question. Sorry folks!

Comment: It's still a quantile. $0<\alpha<1$, so $q$ could be called the $100\alpha$-th percentile. For example, for a random variable $X$ with the standard normal distribution, $P(X\le-0.674)\approx0.25$, so that $X=-0.674$ is (approximately) the 25th percentile.

Comment: besides quantile, there's inverse CDF? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function